# What kind of data type is transfered between Android Facebook SDK and Facebook Backend?

Tags: android, json, facebook

I'm analyzing some security issues due to an app which uses the Facebook SDK.

a) What type has the data which is transferred between the app and the Facebook backend? Is it JSON? Or is it something else?

b) Furthermore is there a "modern" and secure SSL-Communication used? Do I have to deal with certificates or is that managed by the SDK itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data type transferred is JSON through HTTP GET request-response.
The result JSON it's like:

```
{
"id" : "32419183519351",
"bithday": "*****",
"name": "Danilo Dughetti",
...
}
```

For more info try to check the Facebook Graph API.
And for the security question, I know that exists an Acess Tocken system. Actually I don't know if SSL is used.
Hope it can help, bye!